# Installing Driverless AI on AWS

Tags: driverless-ai

I've installed the DAI community app on an AWS instance following these instructions:

http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/install/aws.html

https://localhost:12345 gives me the login screen. The standard credentials "h2oai" and "h2oai" return "Invalid User Id or Password". What are the credentials?

Also, DAI installed to /opt. I do not see the /data and /license folders anywhere. Where are they?

Comment: Hi Karl, what is the full AMI ID you used for the instance?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you are probably using the AWS Marketplace image and not the community ami. The AWS Marketplace image is password protected in order to observe AWS Marketplace standards. The username should be 'h2oai' and the password would be the AWS Instance ID.

With respect to the folders, the AWS Marketplace image uses our Debian install package. See documentation here: http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/install/linux-deb.html for information about which folders are available where. The software will be installed into /opt/h2oai/dai, and you will find the log folder there, but it is better for you to access the logs and such via systemctl and journalctl.

NOTE: additional configurations folder can be found at /etc/dai